# Error in case expression and usage of division operator in round function

Tags: mysql, sql

If a chat is rated 4 or 5, it is a good rated chat. Chats can be rated 1/2/3/4/5. However the code I'm submitting is throwing up errors in the usage of case statement

> (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'case cs.chat_rating when (4,5) then GR when (1,2,3,4,5) then TR
>   end WHERE cs.ag' at line 4).

Also I think my usage of round function and the division operator may be wrong. I need to find the ratio of good to total rating.

```
SELECT Distinct(cm.channel_name), round(GR DIV TR) FROM channel_company AS cc
    LEFT JOIN chat_sessions 
    LEFT JOIN channel_master
    case cs.chat_rating
    when (4,5) then GR 
    when (1,2,3,4,5) then TR end
    WHERE cs.agent_assigned_time >= " "
    AND cs.agent_assigned_time <= " "
    group by 1
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows, not just the first column. I.e SELECT Distinct(cm.channel_name), round(GR DIV TR) is the same as SELECT Distinct cm.channel_name, round(GR DIV TR), and also the same as SELECT Distinct cm.channel_name, (round(GR DIV TR)) etc.

Comment: It's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: Putting a LEFT JOIN's right side table's conditions in the WHERE clause like you do makes the LEFT JOIN behave as a regular INNER JOIN. Move those conditions to the ON clause(s) to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: what is ALIASE  `cc`

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode it is being used for channel_company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT cm.channel_name,
(SUM(case 
    when cs.chat_rating IN (4,5) then 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(case when cs.chat_rating IS NOT NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS ratio_rating 
    FROM
    channel_company as cc 
    LEFT JOIN chat_sessions AS cs ON cs.company_id = cc.company_id
    LEFT JOIN channel_master AS cm ON cc.channel_id = cm.id
    WHERE cs.agent_assigned_time >= '2015-10-28 06:30:00'
    AND cs.agent_assigned_time <= '2015-10-29 02:30:00'
    group by cm.channel_name
```

You missed  `CASE` position  AND some `IN` in `WHEN` condition .You have to mention the correct table aliase for `cc` in `FROM`(You missed it)
Hope this helps

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case cs.chat_rating when 1 in (4,5) then 'GR' when 1 in (1,2,3,4,5) then 'TR' e' at line 2

Comment: round(GR DIV TR) FROM channel_company AS cc, -> What you mean by this

Comment: I am dividing Good ratings by total ratings as obtained from case statement, and then using round statement to round the result. channel_company is the table that has the common columns that are joined upon via the other 2 join statements.

Comment: `GR` div  `TR` .. Both are characters right?  are you counting no. of GR and TR? please explain?

Comment: please give expencted out put?

Comment: Yeah they are characters, but I want to count them. Will the count function be enclosed in the case statement or the case statement be enclosed in the count statement? I figured that the round function was not working because I was feeding it characters but couldn't figure out how to count GR and TR in there.

Comment: also as stated above, your modified query is working except that it is not giving the count for any channel, just showing Null against all channels, TR against one and GR against one.

Comment: Expected output is of the type:
Channel_Name     Ratio of Good Rating to Total Rating
XYZ             0.65
ABC             0.7....

Comment: if a particular channel's rating is 3 then ratio is 3/5?

Comment: If the rating is 3 I am not considering that rating. As mentioned in the question GR = Rating of 4 or 5. TR = Any rating (1/2/3/4/5)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I realized that there are null values also included. Hence changing the denominator of your division, I was able to arrive at the correct values. Thanks a ton once again.

Comment: SELECT cm.channel_name,
(sum(case 
when cs.chat_rating IN (4,5) then 1 ELSE 0 END) / sum( case when cs.chat_rating in (1,2,3,4,5) then 1 else 0 end ) *100) as ratio_rating 
FROM channel_company as cc 
LEFT JOIN chat_sessions AS cs ON cs.company_id = cc.company_id
LEFT JOIN channel_master AS cm ON cc.channel_id = cm.id
WHERE cs.agent_assigned_time >= '2015-10-28 06:30:00'
AND cs.agent_assigned_time <= '2015-10-29 02:30:00'
group by cm.channel_name

This is whats working for me. :)